# Match any unicode Letters with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to match any letters (like MS Office Word find with special character ^$ functionality) with regex.
I've tried with `[a-zA-Z]` but don't match any unicode letters like accent letters or ä, ö, ü, ß. 
I've tried also with `[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]`but there are too many letters. 
Is there any regex to match all this letters?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you didn't try `\w` (word characters)?

Answer (score 2):

This `\\p{L}` regex would match any kind of letter from any language.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/16)

Answer (score 2):

To match any unicode letter in Java use:

```
\\p{L}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\\p{L}` to match any letter, Unicode included.

For fine-tuned matching, you can consult the documentation on [filefront](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm), and combine it with the Unicode features documented in Java Pattern [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Quick example**

```
String input = "ZäöüßÄÖÜß您好";
System.out.println(input.matches(String.format("\\p{L}{%d}", input.length())));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to match not *any* letter (eg Arabic characters), but *Latin* characters:

```
\p{IsLatin}+
```

Using your chars:

```
System.out.println("ZäöüßÄÖÜ".matches("\\p{IsLatin}+")); // true
```